# FFmpeg text is not rendering for indian local language font

Tags: ffmpeg

FFmpeg unable to render the local language font using drawtext. Below is the command
`ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=ntr.ttf:text='తెలంగాణ':fontcolor=white:fontsize=72:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy output.mp4`

and out put is

[image]

On the above the used Telugu font ntr , text is తెలంగాణ.If we compare the text the output text characters are not rendered properly.

Let me know what the issue was. I tried with a couple of languages too but it failed.It would be grateful if anyone could help me.
Thanks

Comment: Try check `unicode combination` and `unicode pre-built`

Comment: @TrươngQuốcKhánh any example?

Comment: Check unicode type in text (by string length or byte array/hex) and check your font may be not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to the way Unicode represents Indian Language Letters.

Few letters are formed by 2 characters. For example, "ke", "ku", "tu", "chi" require 2 characters to be combined. You can find more details in the [Unicode Standard Document](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/ch12.pdf)

I got a workaround for Tamil Language. There are other encodings like TAB, which represent each letter with only 1 character. Text in [Unicode encoding needs to be converted to TAB encoding](http://www.suratha.com/uni2tab.htm) and [Fonts supporting TAB encoding](https://elcot.in/tamil-fonts-and-conversion) to be used in ffmpeg.